# Error trying to create new system call Linux Kernel 4.14.79

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I'm running into issues trying to create a new system call that mimics a calculator in Linux Kernel Version 4.14.79. I'm creating a userspace program that should use this new system call. When I try and compile my userspace program, I get the error:

```
gcc -o test_calc test_calc.c 
test_calc.c: In function 'main': 
test_calc.c:137:30: error: 'SYS_calc' undeclared (first use in this function)
int status = syscall(SYS_calc, param1, param2, operation, &finalTotal);
test_calc.c:102:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I believe I'm making uncessessary additions to the Kernel (I'm implementing the system call twice), as well as missing something in my userspace program.

Steps I have taken to create new system call:

1. Added system call entry to table in `arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl` in the form of:

   ```
   398     common     calc             sys_calc
   ```
2. Added system call implementation to `/kernel/sys.c` in the form of:

   ```
   SYSCALL_DEFINE4(calc, int param1, int param2, char operation,  int* result)
   {
   //do my stuff, update result, return -1 or 0. 
   }
   ```
3. Added funtion declaration to `/include/linux/syscalls.h` in form of:

   ```
   asmlinkage long sys_calc(int param1, int param2, char operation, int* result);
   ```
4. In top level directory of Kernel, I create a new directory. In this directory, I create another directory. In this directory (`/newDirectoryOne/kernelStuff`), I have a `sys_calc.c` file with the following implementation:

   ```
   #include <linux/kernel.h> 


   asmlinkage long sys_calc(int param1, int param2, char operation, int* result)
   {
   //Do stuff, update result, return -1 or 0. 
   }
   ```

In this directory, I have a Kbuild file in form `obj-y += sys_calc.o` and I added the necessary info to the top level Makefile:

```
     core‐y+=kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ newDirectoryOne/kernelStuff/
```

5. My userspace application is in the directory `/newDirectoryOne/userSpaceStuff`, and the relevant portions (my includes and the way I'm calling the system call) of the userspace program is:

   ```
   #include <string.h>
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/syscall.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <signal.h>

   //SYSTEM CALL USED HERE

   int status = syscall(SYS_calc, param1, param2, operation, &finalTotal);
   ```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to either what specifically needs to be done to make a new system call, or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `SYS_calc` needs to be defined in `/usr/include/bits/syscall.h`

Comment: @Barmar There is no 'include' directory in the 'usr' directory of this kernel version

Comment: Take a look in `sys/syscalls` and see what it includes to define all the `SYS_xxx` macros. You need to add this there.